# application.properties not read with @EnableAutoConfiguration and custom spring boot starter

Tags: spring-boot, properties, spring-boot-starter

I try to create a simple custom spring boot starter that read property in `application.properties` :

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ CustomStarterProperties.class })
@Configuration
public class CustomStarterAutoConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private CustomStarterProperties properties;

    @Bean
    public String customStarterMessage() {
        return properties.getMessage();
    }
}
```

with its **ConfigurationProperties :**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom.starter")
public class CustomStarterProperties {

    private String message;

  /* getter and setter */
           ...
}
```

There is also the corresponding `application.properties` and `META-INF/spring.factories` to enable the `autoconfiguration`.

I have another project that declares this starter as a dependency and in which I write a test to see if the customStarterMessage Bean is created :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TotoTest {

    @Autowired
    String customStarterMessage;

    @Test
    public void loadContext() {
        assertThat(customStarterMessage).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

This test fails (even with the appropriate application.properties file in the project) because the `application.properties` seems to not be read.

It works well with a `@SpringBootTest` annotation instead of the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` but I would like to understand why EnableAutoConfiguration is not using my application.properties file whereas from my understanding all the Spring AutoConfiguration are based on properties.

Thanks

Comment: are you using different package names? If the dependency that you are including has a different package, you'll need to also add a `@ComponentScan` for the package from the dependency, besides the package that you have in your second project.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiSfat ! I have tried a `@ComponentScan` with the right package declaration but it did not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@EnableAutoConfiguration` on test classes don't prepare required test context for you.

Whereas `@SpringBootTest` does default test context setup for you based on default specification like scanning from root package, loading from default resources. To load from custom packages which are not part of root package hierarchy, loading from custom resource directories you have define that even in test context configuration. All your configurations will be automatically done in your actual starter project based on `@EnableAutoConfiguration` you defined.

Comment: Thank you @ScanQR !! I made it work by adding `@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)` on my test class.

Comment: @matdan sure. If you find answer useful then do accept it. Thanks!